# Notification Center stuck in landscape orientation

Tags: iphone, notifications

This screenshot pretty much says it all:

[image]

Notification Center seems stuck in landscape mode, based on the height and horizontal distance from the edge to the center pulldown arrow.

- The date and top widget update correctly
- I can interact with (what I can see of) the top widget
- I *can't* swipe the arrow up to dismiss Notification Center
- I *can't* interact with the visible screen "behind" Notification Center

The home button dismisses Notification Center as usual. This behavior has persisted across several restarts.

Interestingly, I can't bring down Notification Center while in real landscape mode. I can get the little arrow tab to come down, but in the wrong spot:

[image]

...but pulling down on the tab just dismisses it.

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot this short of a restore?

iPhone 5, iOS 8.3.

Comment: Did you try just restarting the phone yet?

Comment: @Tyson yup, several times - no change

Comment: Try turning off all Control Center and Notification Center settings, then do a hard restart (hold power & Home button simultaneously until the iPhone boots up). Then change settings back to what you expect and see if it looks ok. Did you, by chance, restore the settings on this device in iTunes using an iPad backup?

Comment: @IconDaemon what do you mean by turning off the settings?

Comment: What's odd is that there is **no landscape mode** in Notification Center on iPhone: it is _always_ portrait; whereas both landscape and portrait are possible on iPad. Anyway - to turn off Control Center options (Settings > Control Center > Access on Lock Screen and Access Within Apps). For Notifications, go to each app in the INCLUDE list and turn off Allow Notifications. The do the hard restart. Do the hard restart anyway, if you haven't already.

Comment: For me, "normal" restart of the phone works... but the problem reappears after some time :/

Comment: I had a [similar problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GlTNl.png) after I handed my 2 1/2 year old son my phone to watch football. The frustrating thing is that I couldn't power down in the ordinary way since the confirmation swipe was hidden. In addition, the bottom half of the screen did not respond to touch. It was irritating, but thankfully the accepted answer worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar happened to me once like this. Try a hard restart by holding both the power and the home buttons until you see the Apple icon appear on the screen. Let me know if that works.